# Customize Facebook's sharer.php to pass metadata of wordpress post (thumbnail and title)

Tags: wordpress, facebook-sharer

I created FB Share button for wordpress post but it does not fetch the metadata from the post. I would like get the thumbnail and the title of the post when clicking share button.

Here is the code I used for that button:

```
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" title="Share on Facebook.">
```

And here is a live website :

http://www.traineffective.com/blog/successful-soccer-players-mentors/

(You can see that it does not pass the permalink and title when clicking share of facebook button )

Any ideas how can I customize sharer.php attributes to pass the link to the post, title and thumbnail ?

Answer (score 0):

The sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter nowadays, all other data will come from the Open Graph tags, you don´t need to specify them in the URL (and you can´t). If it does not work with the permalink, use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/function.urlencode.php).

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags
- http://ogp.me/